# Testing for Active Directory Schema modification (not upgrade)

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, replication, schema, domain-controller

I am trying to test a schema modification. That is i need to add one of the attributes to global catalog by modifying schema , initially in a lab which is exact replica.My questions are below;

-> What tests need to be done post schema change to determine if its safe for production?
-> Apart from measuring changes in DIT size post change, is there a way to find the whole size increase for adding an attribute to GC pre change?

please let me know if any extra questions or info required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty low-risk maneuver. It'll trigger a full sync on every global catalog as the new attribute becomes part of the partial attribute set on each GC. After that full sync, the tests you would need to run are `repadmin /showreps` to verify that domain controllers are still replicating, and then perform a search on the new attribute across domains to verify that adding the attribute to GC replication had the desired effect. (i.e. your searches for the added attribute will be faster than they were before.)  Pretty straight forward.